# Jquery events on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, tooltip, show-hide

I am attempting to make the [Tipsy Tooltip](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) show on click, and disappear on the second click. As well, the tooltip is not showing on the first (odd) click. Instead it shows on the third click.

HTML

```
<p id="more_pricing_info">
<a id="more_pricing_info_tooltip" rel='tipsy' title='Well hello there' onclick='$("#more_pricing_info a[rel=tipsy]").tipsy("show"); return false;'>
    More Info
</a>
</p>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
$('#more_pricing_info').click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        // odd clicks
        $('#more_pricing_info a[rel=tipsy]').tipsy({trigger: 'manual', gravity: 'se'});
    } else {
        // even clicks
    }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element needs an initial "click" value, otherwise the first time you pull it, your `clicks` var is *undefined*. Then you set it to `!clicks`, which evaluates to *false*. Then, the second time you click, your script sees that `clicks` is false, so it skips the tooltip and sets `clicks` to true. On the 3rd click, your code sees that `clicks` is finally true, and the tooltip triggers.

In order to set an initial value for 'clicks, add this **attribute** to your anchor tag:

```
data-clicks="true"
```

Also, you may need to remove the `onclick` attribute in your anchor tag, and just let your javascript code handle the click event.

So, here's your new anchor tag:

```
<p id="more_pricing_info">
<a id="more_pricing_info_tooltip" data-clicks="true" rel='tipsy' title='Well hello there' >
    More Info
</a>
</p>
```